# Whats the issue in reset button of JS counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the script, it work fine as you can see but this reset functionality have some issue, it turns the value to 0 but when again increase the value it starts from the last stored value, whats the issue?

This is the CSS of the counter application this we help you to run this file.

Ans this is the html file is pretty much good but just in issue with script

```js
   
    var counter = 0;
    $("#box").text(counter);

    function reset() {
        counter = 0;
        $("#box").text(counter);
    }

    function inc() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        $("#box").text(counter);

    }

    function dec() {
        counter = counter - 1;
        $("#box").text(counter);

    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.main {
    background: #efefef;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.main h1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#box {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.inc,
.dec {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fcfbfc;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.reset {
    background: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="counter.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif;">Counter App</h1>

        <div id="box">

        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <div class="inc" id="inc" onclick="inc();">
                Increase
            </div>
            <div class="dec" id="dec" onclick="dec();">
                Decrease
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reset" onclick="reset();">
            RESET
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're reset method is not resetting the variable.  It's just changing the displayed value.

Comment: Your `reset()` does not reset the `counter`, just the visual textbox.

Comment: in the reset() function insert: counter = 0; as 2nd line.

Comment: yes i know that, but its a typo or I just miss that line putting the code into this. counter = 0; was there still the code is not working fine. when once you increase the number then reset the number to 0, then when again increase the number it will start from where it was lasted. copy the code and try it as once. Thanks

Comment: now I have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added reset `counter` variable to 0 in `reset()` function.

```js
var counter = 0;
    $("#box").text(counter);

    function reset() {
    counter = 0;
        $("#box").text(0);
    }

    function inc() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        $("#box").text(counter);

    }

    function dec() {
        counter = counter - 1;
        $("#box").text(counter);

    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.main {
    background: #efefef;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.main h1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#box {
    /* width: 50px; */
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.inc,
.dec {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fcfbfc;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.reset {
    background: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="counter.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif;">Counter App</h1>

        <div id="box">

        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <div class="inc" id="inc" onclick="inc();">
                Increase
            </div>
            <div class="dec" id="dec" onclick="dec();">
                Decrease
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reset" onclick="reset();">
            RESET
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check once i am not run in snippet itself.

Comment: It runs now, had some 404 from stack before. Weird.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation

Comment: Why did you pass the parameter value in inc() as inc(1) also dec(1) (onclick), but in function there is no parameter passing

Comment: Forgot to remove it’s not require

Answer (score 0):

## Now i have write a new script for it. Check it out all!

```js
    var a = 0;
    var displayValue = document.getElementById('box');

    var updateValue = function() {
        displayValue.innerHTML = a;
    };

    var add = function(valueToAdd) {
        a += valueToAdd;
        updateValue();
    };
    var sub = function(valueToAdd) {
        a -= valueToAdd;
        updateValue();
    };

    var reset = function() {
        a = 0;
        updateValue();
    };
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.main {
    background: #efefef;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
}

.main h1 {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#box {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #efefef;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.btn {
    display: flex;
}

.inc,
.dec {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fcfbfc;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.reset {
    background: orange;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="counter.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1 style="font-family: sans-serif;">Counter App</h1>

        <div id="box">

        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <div class="inc" id="inc" onclick="add(1);">
                Increment
            </div>
            <div class="dec" id="dec" onclick="sub(1);">
                Decrement
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="reset" onclick="reset();">
            RESET
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```